# Powerpoint 2013 vba create Equation / Mathzone

Tags: vba, math, powerpoint, equation

I am trying to write a macro that inserts an equation into a PowerPoint slide but I cannot find any command to achieve this.

The only math/equation relating element I found so far is MathZones in the Textrange2 class but I don't think you can create a new equation with that. At least I didn't figure out how.

I don't want to insert an Equation.3 object like it is explained in 
[Create new Equation Macro in PowerPoint 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844039/create-new-equation-macro-in-powerpoint-2007) .

The equation should be inserted in the same way as by hitting the Equation button.

I'm searching for hours now without getting even any idea...

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help but I finally found the solution I was looking for. It is way easier than I expected...

```
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("InsertBuildingBlocksEquationsGallery")
```

Full Example:

```
Sub insert_equation()

  Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("InsertBuildingBlocksEquationsGallery")

  With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame
  With .TextRange
      .Font.Size = 16
      .Text = "\omega"
  End With
  End With

  Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("EquationProfessional")

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice!  And thanks for coming back with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

This might help get you started:

Insert an equation into an existing text box then while it's selected:

```
Sub WhatIsTheEquationMadeOf()

Dim x as Long

With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange
   For x = 1 to Len(.MathZones(1).Text)
      Debug.Print AscW(Mid$(.MathZones(1).Text,x,1))
   Next
End With

End Sub
```

That will give you some idea what it's expecting.  Then you may (?) be able to set .Mathzones(1).Text to the same values in another text box as a test to see if the equation appears.